# Use filename as argument in bash alias, with default if it doesn't exist

Tags: bash, scripting

I'm trying to create an alias for a command that has an argument which can either be a filename or a string:

```
command --style filename.style
```

OR

```
command --style "fixed"
```

Is there a way to combine this into a one-liner where I have the style parameter defined with something like:

```
command --style {`find . -name "filename.style"` || "fixed"}
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible; no, this question isn't narrow and specific enough to let us tell you how.

Comment: I just need a working case for the example above; what more info do you require?

Comment: ...f/e, if you know the path of a given file: `[[ -e filename.style ]] && style=filename.style; somecommand --style "${style:-fixed}"`. Or, less efficiently: `somecommand --style "$(if [[ -e filename.style ]]; then echo "filename.style"; else echo "fixed"; fi)"` -- but that's *really* inefficient to run, so I don't recommend it.

Comment: Okay, to start w/ the questions you elided / left open: Do you *really* need recursion in your search? How do you want to handle it if there's more than one result?

Comment: Note too that `find`'s output is ambiguous with the default `-print` action, since it separates filenames by newlines, but filenames are *allowed to contain* newline literals. Someone malicious can `name=$'foo\n/etc/passwd\n '; mkdir -p -- "$name" && touch "$name/hello.style"`, and then you'll have `/etc/passwd` as a line in `find`'s output (typically; some versions escape literal newlines to something like a `?`, but it's not standardized behavior and can't be relied on).

Comment: No recursion is not needed and multiple files should not execute the command but output that there's multiple files; considering all those cases I guess writing a separate function for the alias might be a better choice...

Comment: For a longer discussion of forming command lines with dynamic arguments, see [the relevant subsection of BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050#I.27m_constructing_a_command_based_on_information_that_is_only_known_at_run_time).

Comment: You *can* disable recursion with `find`; that's what `-maxdepth 1` does, f/e. But its use in command substitutions is still problematic if not done carefully; [Using Find](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind) goes into depth on how to do it well; [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls) gives a much briefer high-level overview of some of the things to avoid.

Comment: (Also, the general advice on aliases is "if you have to ask, use a function instead" -- see the irc.freenode.org #bash factoid database entry at http://wooledge.org/~greybot/meta/alias)

Comment: It doesn't have to be the `find` command, I just used that one as an example above; if there's a better command to use than I'm open for that

Comment: ...well, again, *what do you want to branch on*? Is it whether a file exists? If so, I already gave you that in one of the very first comments. Whether a variable is set to a non-empty value? Even easier, then, the shell has a parameter expansion for it built-in. But the question isn't clear enough to be confident right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aliases aren't as good a choice as functions here, since they don't have branching logic support (without jumping through hoops that basically have you assigning a function anyhow). Better to just make the code a function directly:

```
foostyle() {
  if [[ -e filename.style ]]; then
    foo --style filename.style "$@"
  else
    foo --style fixed "$@"
  fi
}
```

...will make `foostyle whatever` run `foo --style filename.style whatever` if `filename.style` exists in the current working directory, or `foo --style fixed whatever` otherwise.

As far as I can tell, that's what you're asking for.

Answer (score 1):

1. Motives and motivations

@CharlesDuffy already forewarned in detail and his warnings should not be taken lightly.

This answer will attempt to be the least worst approach for doing it the wrong way in the rightest way possible, and attempt to address the question raised.

2. Request and requirement

For this exercise we want to create an alias that has an argument which can either be a filename or a string.

3. In the beginning

Reference was made to some `command`, for the purposes of this response we will assume that:

```
$ which command
/usr/bin/command
```

4. Locating a file or defining for `$f`

Ideally we should know the full path to where we can find `filename.style` but will assume that searching for it is the only option. It is strongly advised to rather perform these types of tasks once at startup or as a cron service and assign the resolved value to an environment variable.

The output produced by `find` or `ls` should be considered for interactive maintenance purposes only, [not for use in scripts](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). The preferred directory traversal method in BASH 4+ scripts is [globstar](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#globstar_.28since_bash_4.0-alpha.29) which we will use in these examples.

Activate `globstar` and optionally locate the file in startup script ie. `~/.bashrc` `~/.profile` et al.

```
# activating globstar is not is required for these examples
shopt -s globstar


# optionally search and find filename.style once on startup
for f in **/filename.style; do
    break;
done
if [ ! -e $f ]; then
    f=fixed;
fi
export FILENAME_STYLE="$f";
# Use $FILENAME_STYLE to construct a simple alias
# alias command='/usr/bin/command $FILENAME_STYLE'
```

For this discussion we are going to ignore the file search overhead to illustrate complex functionality in alias implementation. The following command will [expand the glob](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) and define for `$f`:

```
f=(**/filename.style)
```

Should multiple files be discovered only index 0 will be used as `$f == ${f[0]}`.

5. Verify that `$f` exists or assign string `"fixed"`

We are only concerned if `$f` does not exist, using the BASH builtin `test` expression `! -e $f` will provide truthiness, see [`man test` for details](https://ss64.com/bash/test.html).

The quick and dirty shorthand approach is to use `AND_IF &&` which is [also frowned upon](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cmd1_.26.26_cmd2_.7C.7C_cmd3) as it behaves differently to `if..then..else..fi` and may produce unwanted results. These warnings should not be taken lightly, if you are only 99% certain then rather type the 8 extra characters and rest assured.

```
[[ ! -e $f ]] && f=fixed;
```

The preferred method:

```
if [ ! -e $f ]; then f=fixed; fi;
```

6. To alias or to function instead

Enough has been said about the pros and cons we will focus on the differences in implementation.

An alias is meant to be a simple shortcut to avoid typing long commands or always repeating the same options. It cannot accept arguments, instead they are appended and it should be engineered as such to function accordingly.

```
alias command='f=(**/filename.style); [[ ! -e $f ]] && f=fixed; /usr/bin/command "$f"';
```

or:

```
alias command='f=(**/filename.style); if [ ! -e $f ]; then f=fixed; fi; /usr/bin/command "$f"';
```

Functions do take arguments, they cannot be appended to and should be engineered accordingly to forward the arguments appropriately. These examples intentionally mirror the alias implementations to help in comparison.

```
command() { f=(**/filename.style); [[ ! -e $f ]] && f=fixed; /usr/bin/command "$f" "$@"; }
```

or:

```
command() { f=(**/filename.style); if [ ! -e $f ]; then f=fixed; fi; /usr/bin/command "$f" "$@"; }
```

7. Conclusion

In all these examples the `command` is able to define for `$f`, test it's validity and assign the appropriate argument to `/usr/bin/command` while still able to accept additional command line arguments:

```
command arg1 arg2 arg3
```

We have created working aliases and functional functions that satisfy the requirements. Comparing the differences in implementation, considerations for command line argument handling and even though we should avoid expensive overhead it is still possible to add rich functionality to both aliases and functions.

nJoy!